# Override NSSearchField "Clear field" behavior

Tags: cocoa, overriding, nscell, nssearchfield

I need to override `NSSearchField` action which happens when you clear the contents of the field with the "Clear" button.

The default fired selector is private: `_searchFieldCancel`.

**[UPDATE]**

OK, I've found a solution.

But how can I prevent searchField from resigning first responder when clicking on the "Clear" button?

Comment: why did you delete your answer, instead of giving answr in question show it in answer section.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry, it was obvious enough, so I'll post my solution in case anybody needs it:

```
[[[searchField cell] cancelButtonCell] setAction: @selector(desiredSelector)];
[[[searchField cell] cancelButtonCell] setTarget: desiredTarget];
```